# Javascript toString method on Property names

Tags: javascript, object

```
var foo = {unique_prop: 1}, bar = {unique_prop: 2}, object = {};
object[foo] = 'anu';
console.log(object[bar]);
```

The above code outputs "anu".

`toString` method typecast the non-string object into string object.

In the above code `object[bar]` outputs the value as 'anu'.

[Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) says 'since both foo and bar are converted to the same string'

I can't able to understand the java script `toString` method on this code.

can anybody please explain how it works?

Comment: Use function references as property names, they rarely are exact the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `foo`'s value as a property name, it calls `toString` on the `foo` like `object[foo.toString()] = 'anu'`, which if not overridden, will return the same value for every object, which is `'[object Object]'`

So actually you have a property which name is `'[object Object]'`. 
Below `console.log`s will assure that you have a property with name `'[object Object]'`.

```js
var foo = {unique_prop: 1};

var object = {};

object[foo] = 'anu';

console.log(`foo.toString() - ${foo.toString()}`);
console.log(`object.toString() - ${object.toString()}`);
console.log(`object.toString() === foo.toString() ? - ${object.toString() === foo.toString()}`);

for(var prop in object) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Suren Srapyan. You clearly explained the code working functionality. Now my doubt is cleared. Thanks again.